# Is it possible to prevent the buffer of a window from being changed?

Tags: neovim, vim-windows

As title. In fact, I just encountered a situation where I cannot change the buffer of the current window, which is created by some plugin. So I guess there might be some window/buffer option(s) to prevent the current buffer from being changed.

Comment: You can try running `:setl`, which should show all non-default local settings.

Comment: @MartinTournoij After reading all the `:h ...` from the result of `:setl`, I found that `:set buflisted` the most promising one. But then I still got the same result: when I called `:bn` on the window it instead changed the buffer of another window. (still enjoy the try-and-error process since I never know there is a way to list all the local options, might be helpful in the future.)

Comment: What happens when you try to use `:bn`? Do you get an error? Or simply nothing happens?

Comment: @MartinTournoij: Say I have two windows(and both are loaded with a unique buffer): `A`, which is generated by the plugin, and `B`, which is just a normal window I opened for editing my program. In my current situation, if I call `:bn` on `A`, the behavior is like I were calling `:bn` on `B`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij Hi, sorry to tag you again. I just solved my problem brute-forcibly(details below) and you could skip my problem(if you're still doing it) so your time will be saved. I really appreciate your kindness on those reasonable further questions. Happy new year and have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, there is no built-in option to prevent you from **switching**(I used the word *changing* and now I think that is misleading since my question is not about changing the content of a file) the buffer of a given window. (Since the repo. has <200 commits there, so I read through those commit messages and found the one that caused the behavior.)

In that commit, the author uses a function that will be called on two `autocmd`s under a `augroup` named `DapuiWindowsSetup`: `BufWinEnter,BufWinLeave` to achieve the behavior described in my OP. (This might be a piece of useful information if you want to implement the reverse: prevent switching the buffer of a given window, as the commit did.) By deleting that `augroup` I get the original behavior I want. (Regarding the LICENSE of that Repo., I won't post the code here.)

Comment: that is still not safe. You can still do `:noa :bn` and switch away. In short, there is no way to prevent a user from doing this

Comment: Is it https://github.com/rcarriga/nvim-dap-ui? The MIT License should explicitly permit you to post the patch as long as you maintain the License text (IANAL)?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: Thanks for your comment as I never know about `:noa`. But after my trying (I tried `:noa | bn`) the plugin indeed prevent me from switching the buffer.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes that is it. I avoided copy-pasting the LICENSE and/or the link to it since I don't understand how it works precisely.

Comment: @job_start the command would be `:noautocmd bnext`; `noautocmd` is a modifier. The bar-separator in your example is what caused it to fail (since `:noa` by itself is a nop).

Comment: correct, I meant the command as I wrote it, without a `|` in between. Another way to break it: `set eventignore=BufWinEnter,BufWinLeave` , `:bn`

Answer (score 0):

`set nomodifiable`

[help 'nomodifiable'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27nomodifiable%27)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the result of `:set modifiable?` is `modifiable` and I still cannot use `:bn` to change the buffer of that window to another one after testing.

Comment: Well, even if you set 'nomodifiable' a user can simply ':set modifiable'  and start editing the buffer. So it's not completely unchangeable.

Comment: @job_start thats not what I wrote, I wrote `set nomodifiable` I'm not aware of any other option like this, so I still believe answer is correct.

Comment: Understood. In fact, I also tried `:set nomodifiable`, and the results are the same: I cannot switch the buffer of that window.